# Sticky footer ( another version :) )

Tags: javascript, html, css

problem is :

[image]

I want a way to make this :

[image]

(whole image is my window)

please please help me !
it took two days and I found nothing ! :|

javascript, css, using tables, ....
just give me something that works ! :|

UPDATE :

and it happens (the fourth DIV shows itself) when my page's height is lower than window's height

CODES :

the nearest thing I was able to make was (javascript) :

```
while($("#page").height() < wh){
    $("#beautifulizer").css('height', (parseInt($("#beautifulizer").css('height').replace('px', '')) + 500) + 'px');
}
```

and the html :

it's simple :| just 4 divs !

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="beautifulizer"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

CSS :

```
#header : width:100% and height:300px
#content : width:800px
#beautifulizer : width:800px
#footer : width:100% and height:200px;
```

Comment: help yourself by adding some code too... i mean, it's nice to have a picture representation, however we don't see your current code, the one you have tried and is failing... you may want to use [http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Calm down..Provide your existing code. We promised to help you for sure

Comment: Didn't Google help you when you asked him "css sticky footer"? Or what is the specific problem?

Comment: its simple I have three divs like first picture and I need 4 divs like second ! :| and there are just divs with width:100% or 800 and the header and footer have fixed height

Comment: still don't see any code...

Comment: do you need a sticky footer that follows you when you scroll or just a footer that stays in bottom no matter what the height of the page is?

Comment: @webeno you realy don't ?

Comment: the update shows what you tried.. but it's still unclear.. unswer my question if you want help

Comment: ...now I do see your code, but the really relevant one would be if you included the html structure you have plus specify exactly what you want, it's still not clear... and apparently I'm not the only one...

Comment: @EbrahimTahernejad you might consider reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to help you come up with a good question.

Comment: @IderAghbal no I don't need sticky footer, or a footer that stays in bottom, it's really clear in update and i need the div to feel the gap with color ! :|

Comment: now it's clear.. :)
then check Vasily's answer

Comment: and also if you googled up "sticky footer" you would have found http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ (the first result) which is what you want

Comment: @IderAghbal they are not the same ! :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

I make a sticky footer like the website you gave me : [LINK](http://ryanfait.com/html5-sticky-footer/)
then use this :

```
<div style="position:absolute;z-index: -2; width:100%; height:100%;text-align:center">
    <div style="width:990px;height:100%; margin:0px auto;z-index:-1; background-color:#ffcc33;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with css only. You need to create a parent wrapping div and display that as 100% height of the body. Then you can add a footer glued to the bottom of this div.

Comment: sorry if I cannot say what I want to say but that isn't the answer which I want. look if I make the footer to stick to bottom there will be a gap between content and footer I need to fill this gap with the same width of #content and the same background color of #content